# Calender widget generating wrong date format

Tags: spring-roo

I created a very simple Roo project and added a date field (with roo command `field date --class ~.Person --fieldName dateOfBirth --type java.util.Date`).

When running the sample in Chrome, clicking the date field and selecting a date from the calender widget, a date value "`8-aug.-2014`" is inserted in the input field; saving this leads to the following error message:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type java.util.Date for property dateOfBirth; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.Temporal
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date
>   for value 8-aug.-2014; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "8-aug.-2014" is
>   malformed at ".-2014"

Trying to manually enter a date as '8-aug-2014' doesn't work either, because it's changed to '8-aug.-2014' when leaving the field. It is possible to manually enter a value like '8-8-2014' but that does not pass client validation.

Note that it does work in Safari and Firefox, in both cases, the date inserted by the calendar widget is in the format 'Aug 8, 2014'.

Apparently, the widget is broken in Chrome. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the attribute `type=date` in that `input` field? (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

In the past I had the same problems with Chrome when I set the attribute `type=date` ... I solved them by setting `type=text`

Hope it helps